# TrueCrypt error "(drive): refers to a location that is not available"

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt

Scenario: When trying to mount a volume on a particular drive (V:) that I have used many times in the past, I now get the above error.  I am still able to mount the drive with some success on another driver letter.

I checked shares and substituted drives.

Comment: What happens if you try to navigate to V: via an elevated command prompt or Win Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by:

- Attempt to mount the TrueCrypt volume (in my case, V:)
- From an Admin command prompt, run: mountvol /L

  - Note the driver letters in use
- Unmount the TrueCrypt volume
- From an Admin command prompt, run: mountvol /L

  - Note the drive letter that is no longer listed since the dismount (in my case, H:)
- From an Admin command prompt, using mountvol, remove the drive letter identified above

  - e.g. mountvol H: /D